# WebClient says "Update your Browser"

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to read a web page using `WebClient` as shown below but am not successful in doing so. I get the above error response from the webpage. I tried searching a lot on the specific of this issue but haven't been able to find a relevant answer. I tried using proxy as well, but that has the other issue of ServiceAccessManager unable to use https proxies... I would appreciate if you guys can help!!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Update your browser</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <style>
            ...
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            ...
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1>Update your browser</h1>
                        <h3>Unfortunately, we don't support your browser</h3>
                        <p>For your security, we only support browsers using the latest encryption technology.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

    </body>
</html>

         Uri siteUri = new Uri(url);
         using (var client = new WebClient())
         {
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36";               
            try
             {
                 using (var stream = client.OpenRead(siteUri))
                 {
                     string Data = client.DownloadString(siteUri);                         
                 }
             }
             catch (WebException ex)
             {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                    html = sr.ReadToEnd();

                return false;

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

The page or server is trying to detect the type of browser the user is using.  In this case, WebClient doesn't meet it standards.  Maybe it's tried to run some JS?  Or looking for a User-Agent header?  Either way, you don't fit the bill, so the site is giving that message.  There's not really a good definitive answer to this - whats the site?  Can you ask them?

Comment: Sounds right to me, but I don't know enough. Can you provide the OP with a site that shows this?